# Functions on .net5: No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I am exploring running a Function App on `.net5`. Here is what I have so far.

Here is the new `Program` class which replaces the `Startup` class:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder => { configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args); })
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Add Logging
                services.AddLogging();

                // Add HttpClient
                services.AddHttpClient();

                // Add Custom Services
            })
            .Build();

        return host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

I also have this very simple HTTP Triggered Function:

```
public sealed class StorageAccountsFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger<StorageAccountsFunction> m_logger;

    public StorageAccountsFunction(ILogger<StorageAccountsFunction> logger)
    {
        m_logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("v1-get-storage-accounts")]
    public HttpResponseData GetAsync
    (
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "api/v1/storage-accounts")] 
        HttpRequestData httpRequestData, 
        FunctionContext context
    )
    {
        return httpRequestData.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

I have modified my `local.settings.json` to indicate that the Function must run in the isolated mode:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

I start the Function with the following parameters:

```
func host start --pause-on-error --verbose --dotnet-isolated-debug
```

**Question**

When I start the app, I get this warning message:

```
[2021-07-08T13:13:54.813Z] Loading functions metadata
[2021-07-08T13:13:54.814Z] Reading functions metadata
[2021-07-08T13:13:54.815Z] 0 functions found
[2021-07-08T13:13:54.841Z] 0 functions loaded
[2021-07-08T13:13:54.868Z] Generating 0 job function(s)
[2021-07-08T13:13:54.898Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
```

I believe I have followed the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) when running a Function on `.net5` in isolated process. What am I missing?

**Update**

Here is the versions information:

```
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3568 Commit hash: e30a0ede85fd498199c28ad699ab2548593f759b  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.15828.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what was the culprit but I got it working now. I have updated `.Net` to the latest `net5` SDK (5.0.301).

Then I realized that my `local.settings.json` file was missing few information, most importantly I believe is the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` field:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3"
    },
    "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7072,
        "CORS": "*"
    }
}
```

Here is output:

```
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.478Z] EnvironmentVariable FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: dotnet-isolated
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.478Z] EnvironmentVariable FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION: 
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.478Z] Added WorkerConfig for language: dotnet-isolated
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.479Z] Reading functions metadata
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.480Z] 0 functions found
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.489Z] 1 functions loaded
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.506Z] Adding Function descriptor provider for language dotnet-isolated.
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.508Z] Creating function descriptors.
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.563Z] Function descriptors created.
[2021-07-10T12:53:30.572Z] Generating 1 job function(s)
```

**Update**

I ended up with the same problem which required me to add the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` package and update the `.csproj` file to include the following line:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

Comment: At last! Thanks for this - I've been through dozens of S/O questions and answers, and it was the missing `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` package that was causing it to fail silently

Comment: Thank you! Spent an hour trying to figure out why I wasn't getting a Timer function. Ended up being the missing `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` package that I had apparently deleted.